# takeValueFrom update immediately

Tags: swift, cocoa, binding

I want to synchronize the input from a text field to a slider.

I've tried to link them using `takeIntegerValueFrom:` from the `Connections Inspector`.
Is there some way, to update the Value immediately? It seems, that by default the value is changed when focus is lost.

PS.
I've also tried to use the Bond library, but the following line isnt working either 
`textView.reactive.integerValue.bind(to: slider.reactive.integerValue)`

Comment: How about using notification observer to update the value immediately?

Comment: When the user types 125, the slider should go to 1, 12 and 125?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To update the slider based on the input of the text field you can subclass
NSTextField and overwrite keyUp.

```
  override func keyUp(with event: NSEvent) {
        print("Send to slider \(self.intValue)")
  }
```

If its about updating the text filed based on the slider you only have enable "Continuous" for the slider in the control settings. This can be done in Interface builder.